# Specifying table's TD width for HTML email- jsfiddle included

Tags: html

I am trying to create a layout for an HTML email. It's been so long since I've worked with tables, I need a refresher.

I am trying to create a table where each TD is 50% of the total width:

```
<body style="padding-top:20px;">

    <table style="padding:20px;border:1px solid #f0f0f0;background:#FFFFFF;text-align:left;clear:both;margin:0 auto;display:block;width:85%;max-width:600px;table-layout:fixed;">
        <tr style="">
            <td style="width:50%;border:1px solid #ff0000;">left</td>
            <td style="width:50%;">right</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8br3wpL8/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to remove `display: block` from the table style:

```
<table style="padding:20px;border:1px solid #f0f0f0;background:#FFFFFF;text-align:left;clear:both;margin:0 auto;width:85%;max-width:600px;table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr style="">
        <td style="width:50%;border:1px solid #ff0000;">left</td>
        <td style="width:50%;">right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8br3wpL8/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `display:block;` part, everything works

```
<table style="padding:20px;border:1px solid #f0f0f0;background:#FFFFFF;text-align:left;clear:both;margin:0 auto;width:85%;max-width:600px;table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr style="">
        <td style="width:50%;border:1px solid #ff0000;">left</td>
        <td style="width:50%;">right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```